# Zoom into SVG on click and center the clicked element in viewport (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, zooming

I'm working on an interactive layout map using svg, d3.js and jquery-svgpan.js.

This is an example of what it would look like: 
http://maps-charlotte.com/img/1200/panthers-stadium-map.jpg

What I need is: when a user clicks on any of the individual sections, the entire layout zooms in, and the section the user clicked on should be centered on the screen.

This example is closest to what I want to achieve:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

The thing is, I'm adding my svg code inline while the example uses a JSON file, so I can't figure out which javascript code correlates to the map/json and which correlates to the zooming/centering function. (Also I'm new to D3)

This is the code I have so far - it zooms and pans, but doesn't have the click to zoom/center functionality. What would be the best way for me to achieve this?

I appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- pan/zoom -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-svgpan.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <style>
    svg {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>


  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100vh" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <g id="viewport">

      <g>
        <rect x="248" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B2" />
        <rect x="276" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B3" />
        <rect x="304" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B4" />
        <rect x="332" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B5" />
        <rect x="360" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B6" />
        <rect x="388" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B7" />
        <rect x="416" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B8" />
        <rect x="444" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B9" />
        <rect x="472" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B10" />
        <rect x="500" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B11" />
        <rect x="528" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B12" />
        <rect x="556" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B13" />
        <rect x="584" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B14" />
        <rect x="612" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B15" />
        <rect x="640" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B16" />
        <rect x="668" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B17" />
        <rect x="696" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B18" />
        <rect x="724" y="53" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B19" />
      </g>

      <g>
        <rect x="794" y="233" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B21" />
        <rect x="794" y="261" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B22" />
        <rect x="794" y="289" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B23" />
        <rect x="794" y="317" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B24" />
        <rect x="794" y="345" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B25" />
        <rect x="794" y="373" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B26" />
        <rect x="794" y="401" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B27" />
        <rect x="794" y="429" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B28" />
        <rect x="794" y="457" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B29" />
        <rect x="794" y="485" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B30" />
        <rect x="794" y="513" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B31" />
        <rect x="794" y="541" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B32" />
      </g>

      <g>
        <!--reverse-->
        <rect x="248" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B51" />
        <rect x="276" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B50" />
        <rect x="304" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B49" />
        <rect x="332" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B48" />
        <rect x="360" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B47" />
        <rect x="388" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B46" />
        <rect x="416" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B45" />
        <rect x="444" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B44" />
        <rect x="472" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B43" />
        <rect x="500" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B42" />
        <rect x="528" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B41" />
        <rect x="556" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B40" />
        <rect x="584" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B39" />
        <rect x="612" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B38" />
        <rect x="640" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B37" />
        <rect x="668" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B36" />
        <rect x="696" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B35" />
        <rect x="724" y="607" width="28" height="141" class="cls-1" id="B34" />
      </g>

      <g>
        <!--reverse-->
        <rect x="65" y="233" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B64" />
        <rect x="65" y="261" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B65" />
        <rect x="65" y="289" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B66" />
        <rect x="65" y="317" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B67" />
        <rect x="65" y="345" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B68" />
        <rect x="65" y="373" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B69" />
        <rect x="65" y="401" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B70" />
        <rect x="65" y="429" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B71" />
        <rect x="65" y="457" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B72" />
        <rect x="65" y="485" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B73" />
        <rect x="65" y="513" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B74" />
        <rect x="65" y="541" width="141" height="28" class="cls-1" id="B75" />
      </g>

    </g>
  </svg>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

      var w = 960,
        h = 500;

      var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("class", "PiYG")
        .on("mousemove", update);

      // This was added to the example
      var g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('id', 'viewport');

      function update() {}

      $('svg').svgPan('viewport');

    });

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear with the combination of a voronoi and the hard coded rectangles - are we just trying to zoom to a rectangle (or other hard coded svg shape) on click (eg: can I remove the voronoi)?

Comment: @AndrewReid Sorry, you can remove the voronoi parts. I copy/pasted code from a few different examples online, so that must be where that came from (didn't want to delete it in case it interfered with something else)

Comment: @AndrewReid edited the code in my question to remove the unneccessary parts